# C++ "overloading" second default function argument

Tags: c++, default-arguments

Is there a way to choose which function arguments to override in c++ like in Python?

example code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(int a=1, int b=1) {}

int main()
{
    test(b=2);
    cout << "kkk" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is isn't. In C++ you always need to supply the parameters in the order they appear in the function declaration.

A workaround that exists for many cases is to supply overloads to that function.

Comment: ah thank you of course, that would work, much appreciated